# Tabulator: titleFormatter: "rowSelection" when clicking header select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, tabulator

When I click on the checkbox to select/deselect all rows in my table the `headerClick` function doesn't fire (It will fire for everything in the header but the checkbox). This is my column set up for it and I'm just wondering if this is a bug or if there is another way for me to trigger my function of getting all selected rows when I click the select all checkbox. Thanks!

```js
columns: [
    {
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerSort: false,
        visible: true,
        width: 40,
        headerClick: (e, column) => {
            console.log(e);
            let table = column.getTable();
            this.selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
            this.rowCount = this.selectedRows.length;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't say its a "bug", but it looks like you have a feature request, definitely. The code for `rowSelection has :

```js
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

so on it's click, it's not letting anyone else know about it with `stopPropagation()`. And I don't see any code to getHeaderCheckbox() so that you might add your own clickHandler.

So I would go to to GitHub and lodge a feature request to be able to add your own handlers to this item. Unless he's already done it in 5.0 ? I haven't looked at it yet...

in the meantime, you could do your own version of this and not use the `rowSelection` formatter, or you could do a WHOLE lot of work to with `getChildElements()` to get a handle on the actual DOM element and insert your own handler (that would be LAST resort IMHO)

If you ABSOLUTELY must have it NOW (and I would absolutely NOT advise you doing this !!!) :

Give your column a `field` (say "selector" for example) for easy access and after your "new Tabulator()" ...

```js
table.getColumn("selector")._column.titleElement.firstChild.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   console.log(e);
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I did not say this, I was never here ....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to add functionality that isnt needed. The `rowSelection` formatter when used in the `titleFormatter` option will automatically handle the select/deselect all functionality, there is no need to listen to any click events yourself. it will do it all for you.

By adding the additional `headerClick` handler you are immediately negating the selection, by toggling things a second time